# Windows software to see individual images inside of an icon file

Tags: windows, gratis, images, icon

I'm currently looking for a way to view all individual image files inside of a Windows icon file. This has been possible on Windows 7 and 8.1 using the default photo viewer app. This app isn't available on Windows 10 anymore (at least without hacking the registry).

Does anyone know of a free tool capable of doing this? Google doesn't understand my question.

The stock Win 10 Photos App can't do it and neither can any free piece of software that I've tried until now...

Any leads are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do this for free using [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org). Each icon size will open on a new layer. You can also export *.ico files from GIMP.

You could also use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). `convert icon.ico icon.png` should extract all the images contained in the *.ico

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 10, however I came across this after a Google search:  http://www.ico2png.com (warning: This site no longer exists, new content not safe for work)

Upload the ico file and it will show the individual images.

The search terms I used to find this were "ico image extractor."  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently had to deal with .ico files - creating, getting images from, etc.
After a brief google of available programs, I settled on trying out two: "icofx 3" and "RealWorld Icon Editor".  The former is not free, but can be used for a limited "trial period" for free.  The latter is free.

My experience with "icofx 3" was not good: I could not seem to extract images from an .ico file easily.  I could not find a way to put text into and icon.  It seemed to have some bugs in some of its features (e.g. "replacing color" feature did not seem to work.)  It may be that I simply did not get familiar enough with it - perhaps those features are there.  But if I cannot find them without extra effort, it's not well designed in any case.

My experience with "RealWorld Icon Editor" was excellent.  Trivial to install and use, powerful.  It easily performed all the functions I mentioned that I could not get "icofx 3" to do.  In particular, it will do exactly what you require: you can open an .ico file and view and extract the images.  You can find it here: http://www.rw-designer.com/3D_icon_editor.php